# Is it necessary to create a client to gateway VPN tunnel for QuickVPN users on the RV082?

Tags: cisco, configuration, router, linksys, cisco-vpn

Using the [Linksys/Cisco RV082 router](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9926/index.html), is it necessary to create a Client to Gateway tunnel if all of the remote VPN users will be using Cisco's QuickVPN client, or can you simply configure the QuickVPN clients using the VPN Client Access page and not worry about creating a Client to Gateway tunnel? After looking at the [RV082 Manual](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/csbr/rv082/administration/guide/RV082_V10_UG_D-WEB.pdf), the answer doesn't seem clear to me. Thanks.

[VPNClient http://questllc.smugmug.com/Other/Images-Web-Hosting/vpnclient/741693178_2Dnae-M.jpg](http://questllc.smugmug.com/Other/Images-Web-Hosting/vpnclient/741693178_2Dnae-M.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Cisco's support website](https://web.archive.org/web/20110925171229/http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9923/products_qanda_item09186a0080a36516.shtml), the answer is no. To confirm I have deleted all client to gateway tunnels and was able to successfully get QuickVPN to work. The following image from Cisco's support page shows one QuickVPN link active under the *VPN Client Status* and no tunnels defined under *Tunnel Status*:
[image]